# Weird issue with getting value from Dojo textbox

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a login form which used dojo dijit ( dojo version 1.9.1 (43) )

```
<div><input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" type="text" data-dojo-attach-point="loginUserId" data-dojo-props="placeHolder:'%M_AGENT_ID%'" ></div>
```

And a contentWidget initialize here:

```
_contentWidget =new (declare(
                            [_Widget, TemplatedMixin, WidgetsInTemplateMixin],
                            {templateString:  toolbar_html}
                        ));
```

The page loaded without any error and when I manually input some text in that User textbox, the "onchange" can be triggered but
`_contentWidget.loginUserId.get('value')` returns nothing, and when entering text into that textbox the placeholder doesn't disappear as it should.

Could you help me to figure out if there is anything wrong with the dojo widget itself or dojo loader/ initializer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. This issue is due to importing dojo/dijit additional lib multilple times In the above i have these libs imported after importing dojo.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/common/dojo/dojox/widget/Toaster.js?2.7.5.12.14489"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/common/dojo/dojo/cldr/nls/en/gregorian.js?2.7.5.12.14489"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/common/dojo/dojo/cldr/nls/en/number.js?2.7.5.12.14489"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/cim/common/dojo/dijit/form/Textarea.js?2.7.5.12.14489"></script>
```

It may lead to some other errors :" define is not defined.